# Asp.net Mvc site inaccessible after 200 user is online and high cpu usage

Tags: asp.net, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, performance-testing

We are running an Asp.net MVC 4 site on a server and when 200 user is online and doing something on the site. Site becomes inaccessible. When i look cpu and ram usae from server. w3wp.exe and sqlserver.exe are using high cpu and there high disk I/O usage for sql server.

I downloaded Apache JMeter to make load tests over application. I set for a load test with 200 user and set http requestes to home/index.Again there is high cpu usage with w3wp.exe (IIS process) and cannot access site using browser window.

But i dont really know how to identify problem. Where can i find the reason that when 200 user is online, why is w3wp.exe process having high cpu usage and sql server also ?

Comment: check your IIS connection pool limit.

Comment: where can i change it?

Comment: It's the configuration of IIS.

Comment: i dont know where to change it? Is that limit given at installation of IIS? Where can i find that limit value and change it?

Comment: No, i hope we can do it in connection string

Answer (score 2):

There could be lots of issues. What have you tried so far?

I suggest you try some tools like:

- Ants Profiler from Redgate - will help with memory leaks and the like
- analyse your database queries and indexes for a start using whichever tools for your DB
- download Glimpse - useful to have in your dev environment for tracking down issues
- if using an ORM tool like Entity Framework, or NHibernate, consider downloading a free trial of one of Ayende's profiling tools - helps identify many common issues people have with ORM's.
- run the site through YSlow - more to do with client side issues but may help identify if there are too many requests happening per session and things like that

None of these will be the magic bullet, and there are other similar ones available, but these should help you get to the bottom of the issue. Good luck.

Comment: i dont know where to start actually. I just downloded Apache JMeter and sent http requests with it using thread group with 200 users. When i click start and look for CPU monitor. w3wp.exe starts using 40% cpu and i cannot reach site while this load test continues.

Comment: clearly the problem exists, now use tools like I suggest to analyse the different areas. DB indexes issues should be easy to spot. ORM issues should be easy to spot using the orm profilers.